# JTextField Display and Actual Text - Persian/Arabic Numbers

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

We are looking for a way to keep two types of texts for a JTextField

1. Actual value is the value which the user input using keyboard
2. Converted Value is a value which the user see inside that text field (The reason of doing this is that we want to display to our users Persian digits while he/she is typing - Only Display)

And finally the actual text will save inside our database **NOT the Display text**

We have created the text converter for the Display BUT we don't know how to apply this Scenario to the JTextField

Comment: Maybe you could adapt your converter to work as a formatter for a `JFormattedTextField`: [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html), [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html).

Comment: @KevinAnderson I'm actually wrote a custom formatter but I don't know how to keep the original text. the other problem is that because the user might put the cursor anywhere in the text, you dont know in what offset the change has occurred within the Format class because it only has to methods stringToValue and ValueToString.

Comment: Don't think of the problem in terms of just  keeping track of the "original text" so that you can turn it into Persian digits to be displayed.  It's a two-way proposition: every time the user types, you have a new "text" of mixed Persian and Arabic digits which `stringToValue` needs to turn into a "value" of all Arabic digits, and each time the "value" changes, `valueToString` needs to turn it into a new "text" of all Persian digits to be displayed.

Comment: @KevinAnderson Actually I found a way. I will share it here once it got completed

Comment: Please do share when completed. I am curious. I was about to suggest to see if setting a custom document might help - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getDocument-- . Makes me wonder why TextComponents do not have a renderer like some of the other swing components.

Comment: @Veera I already posted the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through this and I came up with this solution.

First we need to show the user persian/arabic digits when they have chosen Persian/Arabic keyboard in their OS and they're typing numbers inside their JTextField. To achieve this I wrote this custom DocumentFilter :

```
public class PersianNumberDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter {
    private static final String REPLACE_CHARS = "0123456789.";

    @Override
    public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String text,
                             AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
        if (text != null && !text.isEmpty() && REPLACE_CHARS.contains(text)) {
            text = doSwap(text);
        }
        super.insertString(fb, offset, text, attr);
    }

    @Override
    public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text,
                        AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
        if (text != null && !text.isEmpty() && REPLACE_CHARS.contains(text)) {
            text = doSwap(text);
        }
        super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length)
            throws BadLocationException {
        super.remove(fb, offset, length);
    }

    public String doSwap(String text) {
        InputContext context = InputContext.getInstance();
        String windowsKeyboardSelected = context.getLocale().toString();
        if (!windowsKeyboardSelected.contains("fa") && !windowsKeyboardSelected.contains("ar")) {
            return text;
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
            if (REPLACE_CHARS.contains(String.valueOf(c))) {
                if (c == '.') {
                    c = ',';
                } else {
                    c = (char) ('\u06F0' - '0' + c);
                    //c = (char) ('\u0660' - '0' + c); Arabic Number Digits
                }
            }
            sb.append(c);
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Next we need a utility class for number and text conversion from and to Persian/Arabic. I wrote this utility class for this matter:

```
public class PersianNumber {
    private static HashMap<Character, String> unicodeMap = new HashMap<>();
    private static HashMap<Character, String> unicodeMapArabic = new HashMap<>();
    private static HashMap<Character, String> unicodeMapViceVera = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        //English/Persian Numbers Map
        unicodeMap.put('0', "\u06F0");
        unicodeMap.put('1', "\u06F1");
        unicodeMap.put('2', "\u06F2");
        unicodeMap.put('3', "\u06F3");
        unicodeMap.put('4', "\u06F4");
        unicodeMap.put('5', "\u06F5");
        unicodeMap.put('6', "\u06F6");
        unicodeMap.put('7', "\u06F7");
        unicodeMap.put('8', "\u06F8");
        unicodeMap.put('9', "\u06F9");

        //English/Arabic Numbers Map
        unicodeMapArabic.put('0',"\u0660");
        unicodeMapArabic.put('1',"\u0661");
        unicodeMapArabic.put('2',"\u0662");
        unicodeMapArabic.put('3',"\u0663");
        unicodeMapArabic.put('4',"\u0664");
        unicodeMapArabic.put('5',"\u0665");
        unicodeMapArabic.put('6',"\u0666");
        unicodeMapArabic.put('7',"\u0667");
        unicodeMapArabic.put('8',"\u0668");
        unicodeMapArabic.put('9',"\u0669");

        //Persian English Numbers Map
        unicodeMapViceVera.put('\u06F0', "0");
        unicodeMapViceVera.put('\u06F1', "1");
        unicodeMapViceVera.put('\u06F2', "2");
        unicodeMapViceVera.put('\u06F3', "3");
        unicodeMapViceVera.put('\u06F4', "4");
        unicodeMapViceVera.put('\u06F5', "5");
        unicodeMapViceVera.put('\u06F6', "6");
        unicodeMapViceVera.put('\u06F7', "7");
        unicodeMapViceVera.put('\u06F8', "8");
        unicodeMapViceVera.put('\u06F9', "9");
        //Arabic English Numbers Map
        unicodeMapViceVera.put('\u0660', "0");
        unicodeMapViceVera.put('\u0661', "1");
        unicodeMapViceVera.put('\u0662', "2");
        unicodeMapViceVera.put('\u0663', "3");
        unicodeMapViceVera.put('\u0664', "4");
        unicodeMapViceVera.put('\u0665', "5");
        unicodeMapViceVera.put('\u0666', "6");
        unicodeMapViceVera.put('\u0667', "7");
        unicodeMapViceVera.put('\u0668', "8");
        unicodeMapViceVera.put('\u0669', "9");
    }

    public static String getPersianNumber(String englishNumber) {
        if (!englishNumber.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")) {
            throw new NumberFormatException("the input [" + englishNumber + "] is not a number!");
        }

        char[] numChars = englishNumber.toCharArray();
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < numChars.length; i++) {
            builder.append(unicodeMap.get(numChars[i]));
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

    public static String getEnglishNumber(String persianNumber) {
        char[] numChars = persianNumber.toCharArray();
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < numChars.length; i++) {
            String value = unicodeMapViceVera.get(numChars[i]);
            if(value == null){
                builder.setLength(0);
                builder.append(persianNumber);
                break;
            }
            builder.append(unicodeMapViceVera.get(numChars[i]));
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

    public static boolean isAPersianNumber(String persianNumber){
        char[] numChars = persianNumber.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < numChars.length; i++) {
            String value = unicodeMapViceVera.get(numChars[i]);
            if(value == null){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static String convertToStringWithPersianNumber(String input){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for(char c : input.toCharArray()){
            String ch = unicodeMap.get(c);
            if(ch != null){
                sb.append(ch);
                continue;
            }
            sb.append(c);
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static String convertToStringWithEnglishNumber(String input){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for(char c : input.toCharArray()){
            String ch = unicodeMapViceVera.get(c);
            if(ch != null){
                sb.append(ch);
                continue;
            }
            sb.append(c);
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getEnglishNumber("۹۶۵۹۴۵۴"));
        System.out.println(getPersianNumber("9999999999999651221"));
        System.out.println(getPersianNumber(59683399623213L + ""));
    }
}
```

Finally We need a Custom JTextField because we want control our inputs and outputs and convert them accordingly from-to our needs:

```
public class JPersianTextField2 extends JTextField {


    public JPersianTextField2() {
//        Hopefully someday (Oracle Love Iranians) and create This Locale for us
        Locale locale = new Locale("fa", "IR");
//        Locale locale = new Locale("ar", "KW");
        ComponentOrientation farsiOrientation = ComponentOrientation.getOrientation(locale);
        super.applyComponentOrientation(farsiOrientation);
        PlainDocument doc = (PlainDocument) super.getDocument();
        doc.setDocumentFilter(new PersianNumberDocumentFilter());
        super.setColumns(25);
    }

    @Override
    public String getText() {
        String tmp = super.getText();
        if (tmp != null && !tmp.isEmpty())
            return PersianNumber2.convertToStringWithEnglishNumber(tmp);
        else
            return super.getText();
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(String t) {
        if (t != null && !t.isEmpty())
            super.setText(PersianNumber2.convertToStringWithPersianNumber(t));
    }

}
```

With this custom JTextField in place you can convert to English digit when you want to fetch the result of the JTextField and convert to Persian digit when you want to set a String which has English digits.

And Finally here is the test for the component :

```
public class MyFormatterTest extends JFrame {

    public MyFormatterTest() {

        setTitle("Example");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("text :");
        JPersianTextField2 tf = new JPersianTextField2();
        tf.setText("سلام من مهدی هستم برنامه نویس ارشد 31 ساله"); //Hi This is mehdi, 31 years old Sr. software developer
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(tf);

        JButton button2 = new JButton();
        button2.setText("getText");
        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println(tf.getText());
            }
        });

        panel.add(button2);


        getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        pack();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Available Locales inside Your JVM
        for (Locale l : Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
            System.out.println(l.getCountry() + ":" + l.getLanguage());
        }

        MyFormatterTest mfe = new MyFormatterTest();
        mfe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mfe.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Hope this is useful for you ...